# Best tree type for Dictionary implementation

Tags: java, dictionary, tree, binary-tree, avl-tree

I am required to implement general dictionary using Java that will allow efficient O(logN) or better insertions, deletions and random access.

My question is: what type of tree will give me the best time performance for a huge amount of insertions and deletions? AVL, RB, Binary Search, Splay or B-Trees?

Comment: Self balancing trees like AVL, RB trees always have a higher insertion, deletion cost because of the extra processing involved in balancing the tree. On the other hand, these are better for retrievals, especially in large number of nodes. BSTs are best insertions and deletion wise but not better than balanced trees for access. For your requirements, it depends - but typically insertions and deletions to a dictionary are rare, and reads are frequent, hence I would think self balancing trees are a better choice

Answer (score 1):

You can use [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure for implementing dictionary.For implementing it first you have to create trie which will take O(nlogn) time.After that you can search,insert & delete  word in O(logn).
For more understanding you can refer [NPTEL LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhAUk63tLRM),which contain basic of tire data structure.